# Center <-> User model relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My site will have many centers. The administrator of each center should being able to login and edit the center AND being able to create more users that have access to that center edition.

The first thing I thought of is to create 1-N Center-User relation, but not sure if is the right one. Looking to some other posts I realized that maybe using a 1-1 relation might not be a bad idea.

What would be the best solution model wise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment of one center to user you can do something like this.

A User can have one Center and create more (so 1+) and can add more users to it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :center
  #...
end

class Center < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users    
  #...
end
```

Then you can do things like

```
current_user.center
current_user.create_center(params)
some_center.users << user_to_add
```

Comment: A user cannot have/belong to more than one center.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Will there be more than 1 admin for a center?

What about a Users -> Roles -> Center

User has_many roles, Role belongs_to a center

This way you could have a user who is a role 'admin' for two different centers and the same user could be a role 'normal user' at another center. This is in my mind most flexible, not sure if its more flexible than what you need.